# use of ScardConnect function (winscard.dll) in Wcf

Tags: c#, wcf, dll, smartcard, winscard

I am trying Connecting to smartcard with using connect function of winscard.dll in my WCF project. Wcf service, is publishing with remote machine which machine is installed on windows server 8.1

ScardConnect function is returning value of 6.

```
public int Connect()
                {
                    int returnCode = -2;
                    string[] tempStr = new string[3];

                    returnCode = ModWinsCard.SCardEstablishContext(ModWinsCard.SCARD_SCOPE_USER,
 0, 0, ref hContext);

                    if (returnCode == ModWinsCard.SCARD_S_SUCCESS)
                    {
                        returnCode = ModWinsCard.SCardConnect(hContext, "ACS ACR1281 1S Dual Reader PICC 0", ModWinsCard.SCARD_SHARE_SHARED, ModWinsCard.SCARD_PROTOCOL_T0 | ModWinsCard.SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1, ref hCard, ref pdwActiveProtocol);

                        if (returnCode == ModWinsCard.SCARD_S_SUCCESS)
                            return 1;
                        else
                            return returnCode;
                    }
                    else
                        return returnCode;
                }


  Interface (IService1)
```

[OperationContract]
        [FaultContract(typeof(Service1))]
        int Connect(int hContext, string szReaderName, ref int phCard, ref int ActiveProtocol);

ScardConnect function

```
[DllImport("winscard.dll")]
    public static extern int SCardConnect(int hContext, string szReaderName, int dwShareMode, int dwPrefProtocol, ref int phCard, ref int ActiveProtocol);
```

What does it mean return code '6'.

Note: Wcf project build action : x86
Client project build action: x86

Comment: Can you share the more code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use of ScardConnect function in Wcf on windows server 2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33348948/use-of-scardconnect-function-in-wcf-on-windows-server-2012)

Comment: Ok I edited. Can you check please? @MichaelRoland

Comment: Well, still both questions ask exactly the same. Thus close one of the question or risk both being closed as duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Check the value of "hContext". Possible error in name of reader.So I would suggest you first call [SCardListReaders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379793(v=vs.85).aspx) function to get the exact reader name.

Comment: I am using reader name in parameter and I can take value of hContext from SCardEstablishContext function. In desktop application the function (Connect) is runnign true. But if using in WCF project and after publishing it returns '6'.  have an idea ?  @vikky

Comment: Ok. I am edited it. All of codes in here. Only I want to connect to card reader with WCF using to winscard.dll. if I can see, I can complete to planning phase of my project. @vikky

Comment: You proved that stack overflow is a better documentation than MS docs. Thank you kind stranger.

Comment: The hContext was key, I didnøt store and reuse it. (context handle)
The 6 is found here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-
(handle not correct)